# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).load(...).modal is not a function on re-opening modalbox after close

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).load(...).modal is not a function

I can see this error in console when I close a modal and try to reopen modal box again.
Sometime it works for 2-3 times then giving this error.

Can anyone suggest me what may be the issue?

I have added a div on a page

```
<div class="modal fade" id="loadmodalbox" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

this is the link to open the modal

```
<button class="btn btn-default openmodal" modalbox="affiliateprogrammodal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#affiliateprogrammodal" bid="'.$company['User']['u_id'].'">'.$company['User']['u_text_for_blue_button'].'</button>
```

then I am loading this different modals using following code:

```
$('.openmodal').click(function(e){ 
e.preventDefault();
var modalbox = $(this).attr('modalbox'); 
var companyid = '';
if(modalbox=='commentmodal') {
    companyid = $(this).attr('companyid');
    companyid = '/'+companyid;
}
if(modalbox=='affiliateprogrammodal') {
    companyid = $(this).attr('bid');
    companyid = '/'+companyid;
}
$('#loadmodalbox').load('<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'loadmodalbox')); ?>/'+modalbox+companyid).modal({
                              keyboard: false,
                              show:true,
                              backdrop:'static'
                            });
});
```

Comment: Please include some code demonstrating what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please check my updated question. Hope it will help you to diagnose the problem

Comment: Consider using HTML5 `data-*` attributes for custom attributes like so: `<div data-modalbox="any_value">` and javascript `$(this).data('modalbox')`.

Comment: Can you suggest me how to use it. I am new to it.

Comment: I think your problem in `<?php echo Router::url(` because your snippet sometimes can echo empty value. Fix it by adding checking of that, and your problem should be resolved.

Comment: @VictorPerov the element is getting response from ajax and content is loaded in the modal element. It is just that it is not opening the modal. First time, it loads fine but after 2-3 times it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Could you add your HTML page and JS file? From what we have, it *might* be a problem of page not being loaded yet. This would be the case if your modal is showing, but there is no content.

In that case, try calling the `.modal()` method in load callback like this.

```js
$('.openmodal').click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();

    var modalbox = $(this).data('modalbox'); 
    var companyid = '';
    
    if(modalbox=='commentmodal') {
        companyid = "/" + $(this).data('companyid');
    }
    
    if(modalbox=='affiliateprogrammodal') {
        companyid = "/" + $(this).data('bid');
    }

    var url = '<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'loadmodalbox')); ?>/' + modalbox + companyid;
    $('#loadmodalbox').load(url, function(){
        $(this).modal({
          keyboard: false,
          show: true,
          backdrop: 'static'
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="loadmodalbox" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>

<button class="btn btn-default openmodal" data-modalbox="affiliateprogrammodal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#affiliateprogrammodal" data-bid="'.$company['User']['u_id'].'">'.$company['User']['u_text_for_blue_button'].'</button>
```

Comment: I could duplicate the error you are saying at first, but now the form is working just fine. Did you fix it already?